# When Checkbox is Checked Expand Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
<div style="display:none">
This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
```

Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please stop writing thanks and tags -- especially silly ones!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+toggle

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will show it when the checkbox is checked, and hide it again when the checkbox is unchecked:

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

...although it would be better if you'd assign that DIV an id, so it could be selected more quickly:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
<div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
    This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pTA3Y/

If you want to show the div without hiding it again, replace `.toggle()` with `.show()`.

Comment: Why does the script have to be after the content?

Comment: Because I didn't use `$(document).ready`. If you do, then it doesn't.

Comment: How would you fix the problem I have with this function? If I start with div visible, checking the checkbox makes div disappear and unchecking makes it appear again.

Comment: This isn't a JS issue. Either start with the div hidden, or start with the box checked.

Comment: So the script doesn't actually see the checkbox state? It just notices the change?

Comment: That's what `.toggle()` does, yes. If you want it to reflect the checkbox's exact state (checked=visible, unchecked=hidden), try: `$('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));` and make sure the initial states match.

Comment: Please answer this! How can you make this method work with more than one checkbox?

Comment: anyone can give a try to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307407/2218697) too, it worked fine for me, hope helps.

Answer (score 6):

Attach a `change` event, and check whether a checkbox is checked or not. If the checkbox is checked, show the div. Otherwise, hide it:

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```

You should also have a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com), before asking such a trivial question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#mycheckbox").change(function(){ 
    $(this).next().toggle(this.checked); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for only css solution, then this can help you.

```
#toggle-content{
display:none;
}
#mycheckbox:checked ~ #toggle-content{
  display:block;
  height:100px;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/3166/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mycheckbox").click(function() { $(this).next("div").toggle() })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input#mycheckbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked") {
        $("div").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("div").slideUp();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#mycheckbox").checked) {
   $("div").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
  $(document).on('ready',function() {
    $('#checkbox').on('change',function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            console.log("checked");
        } else {
            console.log("unchecked");
        }
    })
});
```