# How to show/hide an element on checkbox checked/unchecked states using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
   <fieldset class="question">
       <label for="coupon_question">Do you have a coupon?</label>
       <input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />
       <span class="item-text">Yes</span>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="answer">
       <label for="coupon_field">Your coupon:</label>
       <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field"/>
   </fieldset>
```

And I would like to show/hide the "answer" fieldset (default is hidden) after a click on the checkbox in fieldset "question" How to do that. I wasn't able to do that using the technique for a classic elemetn like:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){

        $('.question').live('click',function() {
                 $('.answer').show(300);
            }
            ,
            function(){
                $('.answer').hide(200);
            }
        );

    });
</script>
```

Could somebody help me how to do that using checkbox? Also if possible to null (uncheck) the checkbox when it's hidden.

Comment: :please take a note that .live() is deprecated since version 1.7 of jQuery, instead use .on() as given in the answer by Arun

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Attach `onchange` event to the checkbox:

```
<input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged()
    {
        if($('.coupon_question').is(":checked"))   
            $(".answer").show();
        else
            $(".answer").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 56):

Try this

```
$(".answer").hide();
$(".coupon_question").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".answer").show(300);
    } else {
        $(".answer").hide(200);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDsCM/)

Comment: +1 for hiding with jquery instead of display:none; in css. This seems to be the correct way, just in case some user might have js disabled.

Comment: @EswaraReddy, +1, this is the best answer I have found so far

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Simplest - and I changed the checkbox class to ID as well:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#coupon_question").on("click",function() {
    $(".answer").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.answer { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="question">
  <label for="coupon_question">Do you have a coupon?</label>
  <input id="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />
  <span class="item-text">Yes</span>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="answer">
  <label for="coupon_field">Your coupon:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Register click events to all checkboxes inside question element
    $(document).on('click', '.question input:checkbox', function() {
        //Find the next answer element to the question and based on the checked status call either show or hide method
        $(this).closest('.question').next('.answer')[this.checked? 'show' : 'hide']()
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ysuWK/)

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Register click events to all checkboxes inside question element
    $(document).on('click', '.question input:checkbox', function() {
        //Find the next answer element to the question and based on the checked status call either show or hide method
        var answer = $(this).closest('.question').next('.answer');

        if(this.checked){
            answer.show(300);
        } else {
            answer.hide(300);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Your example is too complicated(in the terms that it's very hard to understand for a beginner; event though it's probably an efficient piece of code), could you comment it please. I need to run different things except show and hide. Is this the only way how to do the thing I want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        $('.coupon_question').live('click',function() 
        {
            if ($('.coupon_question').is(':checked')) {
                $(".answer").show();
            } else {
                $(".answer").hide();
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".question", function(e) {
       var checked = $(this).find("input:checkbox").is(":checked");
       if (checked) {
           $('.answer').show(300);
       } else {
           $('.answer').hide(300);
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by css :has() CSS pseudo-class

```css
.answer{
display:none;
}
.question:has(input[type="checkbox"][value="1"]:checked) ~ .answer {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="question">
       <label for="coupon_question">Do you have a coupon?</label>
       <input class="coupon_question" type="checkbox" name="coupon_question" value="1" />
       <span class="item-text">Yes</span>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="answer">
       <label for="coupon_field">Your coupon:</label>
       <input type="text" name="coupon_field" id="coupon_field"/>
   </fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <label  onclick="chkBulk();">
    <div class="icheckbox_flat-green" style="position: relative;">
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBulkAssign" runat="server" class="flat" 
       Style="position: 
         absolute; opacity: 0;" />
      </div>
      Bulk Assign
     </label>



    function chkBulk() {
    if ($('[id$=chkBulkAssign]')[0].checked) {
    $('div .icheckbox_flat-green').addClass('checked');
    $("[id$=btneNoteBulkExcelUpload]").show();           
    }
   else {
   $('div .icheckbox_flat-green').removeClass('checked');
   $("[id$=btneNoteBulkExcelUpload]").hide();
   }
```