# checkboxes checked - show its correspondig div

Tags: jquery

I found this script where one checkbox (once checked) shows the corresponding div. 
[When Checkbox is Checked Expand Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996291/when-checkbox-is-checked-expand-div)

But I have multiple checkboxes, which shows its corresponding div once checked.

I tried to add the following to the html file but that didn't work:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
<div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
  This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
```

Comment: You question is basically the same as the linked one, so i don't understand why you posted this question.

Comment: Hi , you need to post the javascript that you've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply use CSS `:checked` property for this:

```css
input + div {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
<div id="mycheckboxdiv">
  This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox1" id="mycheckbox1" value="0" />
<div id="mycheckboxdiv1">
  This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
```

Comment: Thks. it seems to work now but how do I get the checkboxes to be underneath each other.. I tried adding '<div style="clear: both;"></div>' but then it goes wrong

Comment: @MK69 Add `input {display: block;}`

Comment: I've added a fiddle but have a problem with the first checkbox. It behaves different from the other ones. https://jsfiddle.net/mk13011969/61eehop9/

Comment: What's the script doing there @MK69? **Did I add any script?** Remove the script and tell what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kumar.. it works indeed without the javascript :-)

Comment: The result is now however that I cannot add text to the checkbox like:    `<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />cars` or `<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />trains`.. Trains or Cars will be put underneath the checkbox. @praveen Kumar

Comment: @MK69 Ah... I get that.

Comment: So how can I get the text (trains or cars) NEXT to the checkbox?

Comment: @MK69 I am still thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" data-divid="mycheckboxdiv"/>
    <div id="mycheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
    This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
    </div>

    //js code

    $(document).body(function(){
     $("input[type='text']").change(function(){
        var val=$(this).attr('data-divid');
       if($(this).attr('checked')){
         $("div [id='"+val+"']").show();}
       else{
         $("div [id='"+val+"']").hide();}        
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to wrap your items in a container div and when user checks the check box,use `closest()` to get the container div,then use `find` to get the associated text div and show/hide it.

*I prefer using `closest()` and `find()` than `next()` method because the first one will work even if you add some new element in between your checkbox and the associated div in the future.*

```
<div class="itemContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" value="0" />
  <div id="mycheckboxdiv" class="meta" style="display:none">
      This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
   </div>
</div>
```

And your jQuery code to handle the checkcbox checcked event

```
$(function(){

  $("input[name='mycheckbox']").change(function(e){

     var _this=$(this);
     if(_this.prop("checked"))
     {
        _this.closest(".itemContainer").find(".meta").show();
     }
     else
     {
         _this.closest(".itemContainer").find(".meta").hide();
     }
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zeduzet/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: I like your script but it works only for all checkboxes named "mycheckbox".... The checkboxes in my application are named "compid.$thistag_id"  where $thistag_id is a variable. How can I change the script as such that it works with all checkboxes starting with the name: compid (whatever the variable is)

Comment: You can do a starts with jQuery library Take a look  http://jsbin.com/tiqiga/edit?html,js,console,output